# 1136 error in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO data_prediction_model
select *, ( 
CASE WHEN ( offer_category like 'Everyday Low Prices on Receipe%'
OR offer_category like 'Every Day Low Prices%'

) THEN "EDLP"


ELSE
CASE WHEN (offer_category like 'Buy More & Save More%'
OR offer_category like 'Buy and Get Free'
) THEN "B1G1"

ELSE 
CASE WHEN (offer_category like 'Offer on Activation/Qualification%'
OR offer_category like 'Save on Purchase of select Products/Plans%'
OR offer_category like 'Coupons Offers%'
OR offer_category like 'Digital Coupons Offers%'
OR offer_category like 'Discounted Products%'
OR offer_category like 'Exchange Offers%'
OR offer_category like 'Multiple Brand Offers%'
OR offer_category like 'Free with Rebate'
) THEN "Discounts"

END END END) AS offer_category
FROM data_offer;
```

Comment: Put some more information with this. 
Check if its a problem with the column count as well.
Take help from Google before posting questions in SO.

Answer (score 0):

From the sql query u stated, i assume is your `CASE` statement when wrong

```
INSERT INTO data_prediction_model
select *, ( 
CASE WHEN ( offer_category like 'Everyday Low Prices on Receipe%' OR 
            offer_category like 'Every Day Low Prices%' ) 
     THEN "EDLP"
     WHEN (offer_category like 'Buy More & Save More%' OR 
           offer_category like 'Buy and Get Free') 
     THEN "B1G1"
     WHEN (offer_category like 'Offer on Activation/Qualification%' OR           
           offer_category like 'Save on Purchase of select Products/Plans%' OR
           offer_category like 'Coupons Offers%' OR 
           offer_category like 'Digital Coupons Offers%' OR 
           offer_category like 'Discounted Products%' OR 
           offer_category like 'Exchange Offers%' OR 
           offer_category like 'Multiple Brand Offers%' OR 
           offer_category like 'Free with Rebate' ) 
     THEN "Discounts"
END) AS offer_category
FROM data_offer;
```

The correct CASE statement order, 
should be like this following pattern

```
CASE 
    WHEN condition 1 THEN value 1
    WHEN condition 2 THEN value 2
    ELSE value 3
END
```

instead of the pattern you do, which looks like this

```
CASE
     WHEN condition 1 THEN value 1
ELSE CASE 
     WHEN condition 2 THEN value 2
     END 
END
```

Hope it help ya.

Comment: INSERT INTO data.data_prediction_model
select *, ( 
CASE
      WHEN offer_category like 'Everyday Low Prices on Receipe%' THEN "EDLP"
      WHEN offer_category like 'Every Day Low Prices%' THEN "EDLP"
     
     WHEN offer_category like 'Buy More & Save More%' THEN "B1G1" 
      WHEN     offer_category like 'Buy and Get Free'THEN "B1G1"
     
     ELSE   "DISCOUNT"
     
END) AS offer_category
FROM data_offer; GOT THE SAME ERROR AGAIN

Comment: as @zedfoxus stated below .... 1136 error is about your insert statement has problem, try to check your data_prediction_model table column, and your insert value... see whether they match the amount and data type or not... credit belong to him

Answer (score 0):

1136 error relates to mismatching columns in table and insert.

For example:

```
mysql> create table test (id int, name varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (1, 'test', 'hello');
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Notice that providing an additional value in the form of `'hello'` throws 1136 error. Table has 2 columns. Providing 2 values of the correct datatype will succeed like so:

```
mysql> insert into test values (1, 'test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
```

Double-check the column count in data_prediction_model is the same as column count in data_offer + case statement(s). Case statement creates a new field for insertion.

EDIT:

In order to solve the problem, list out all the columns from data_prediction_model. List out all the columns from data_offer. data_offer should have 1 less column than data_prediction_model.

Comment: @akshay can you add the output of `show create table data_prediction_model` and `show create table data_offer`?